# Cannot access contact phone numbers

Tags: api, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS API to access contacts,
but cannot access contact phone numbers!

It looks that ContactSchema.PhoneNumbers are not accepted in the view.Property in initial fetch

Currently I have:

```
        ItemView view = new ItemView(numItems);

        view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, new PropertyDefinitionBase[] { ContactSchema.DisplayName} );

        PropertySet PropSet = new PropertySet();
        PropSet.Add(ContactSchema.DisplayName);
        PropSet.Add(ContactSchema.PhoneNumbers);


        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;

        do
        {
            findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, view);

            if (findResults.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                service.LoadPropertiesForItems(findResults.Items, PropSet);
                foreach (var item in findResults.Items)
                {
                    // Display the list of contacts. 
                    if (item is Contact)
                    {
                        Contact contact = item as Contact;
                        PhoneNumberDictionary ph = contact.PhoneNumbers;
                        // ph is empty here!
                    }
                }
            }
            view.Offset += findResults.Items.Count;
        } while (findResults.MoreAvailable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there buddy just add each phone number type you wish to read/write to the property set and you got it!!!

```
Private ReadOnly PhoneFields As PropertySet = New  PropertySet(ContactSchema.PhoneNumbers, ContactSchema.MobilePhone, ContactSchema.CarPhone, ContactSchema.HomePhone,
                                                                  ContactSchema.HomePhone2, ContactSchema.HomePhone2, ContactSchema.BusinessPhone, ContactSchema.BusinessPhone2,
                                                                  ContactSchema.BusinessFax, ContactSchema.OtherFax, ContactSchema.HomeFax, ContactSchema.Pager,
                                                                  ContactSchema.OtherTelephone, ContactSchema.Callback, ContactSchema.CompanyMainPhone, ContactSchema.PrimaryPhone,
                                                                  ContactSchema.AssistantPhone, ContactSchema.RadioPhone, ContactSchema.TtyTddPhone, ContactSchema.Telex)
```

Etc, etc.

I just built a contact sync Windows service any questions ask me twittet @rojobo

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem: both .PhoneNumbers and each phone number type are required when fetching a contact

Comment: I'm glad I could help any more questions let me know I know its hard with the lack of documentation.